# Role of Impersonation on service account when using EWS

Tags: .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I created an application that takes the service account credentials and asking the user to create a service account and assign Impersonation role to it, so that I can access all the mailboxes. So here, can I restrict the impersonation to read access only so that I can just read the mailboxes instead of having full access to the mailboxes. How can I do that?

Thanks,
Rajesh

Answer (score 1):

No EWS Impersonation is All or nothing eg once you have assigned a user impersonation rights the right they impersonate is the owner of the Mailbox (this is important if admins look at audit logs). If you want to do constrained authentication in EWS you need to use delegation and use the Add-MailboxFolderPermission to just grant the applicable rights to whatever folder you need the application to access. (From an admin perspective this will be easy to track in Audit logs).

If your using Office365 you can do constrained Authentication using the new REST Api's and Oauth2 authorization framework.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks for the info. In my application, I am trying to stream notifications of users inbox folder. Can I still do this with the service account without using Impersonation. Just to confirm?

Comment: Yes you can do it without impersonation, however you may start to run into problems with throttling eg EWSMaxSubscriptions so impersonation is one way of avoiding issues with this as the Subscription is charged to the mailbox your impersonating. If you can modify the throttling policies for the service account then that will help you work around that.